# Compress a very large string to smallest string as possible in java

Tags: java, android

I want to Compress very large string to smallest string as possible, because i want to send it by sms.

i am currently using this Encoding Decoding methods but it gives me a very large Cipher Text

String LongText="Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! " +
                "Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! " +
                "Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! " +
                "Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! " +
                "Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! "

```
public byte[] Encoding(String PlainText)
{
    byte[] encodeValue = Base64.encode(PlainText.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodeValue;
}

public String Decoding(byte[] CipherText)
{
    byte[] decodeValue = Base64.decode(CipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return new String(decodeValue);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a compression algorithm, like ZIP or GZIP?

Comment: You are not compressing the text, you are encoding it in base64. Try using a built-in compression algorithm such as [GZIP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html). Note that compressed data is usually a ``byte[]`` and pressing that into an sms might cause other problems.

Comment: yes yes i did Darth Android

Answer (score 0):

You could use Huffman compression but that of course means you have to compress at sender and decompress at receiver side. The more common characters there are in the message, the better the compression rate will be.

Comment: thank you, i will try it.
I've tried many Compression and Encoding methods, but it doesn't gives me a satisfying result, but i didn't tried Huffman yet